# Is $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$ ever the union of a chain of proper subgroups each isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, abelian-groups

Recall that the covering number $cov(B)$ is the least cardinal $\kappa$ such that $\kappa$ meagre sets cover the real line. Andreas Blass and John Irwin http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/bb.pdf prove, among many other results, that $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$ (the infinite abelian group of integer-valued sequences under addition) is never the union of a chain of proper subgroups each isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$, if the chain has length less than $cov(B)$. They note it might be possible to remove the hypothesis on the length of the chain. However, they raise the **question** whether e.g. under $CH$, $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$ could be the union of a chain of proper subgroups each isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$. If the chain $\lbrace A_{\alpha} : \alpha < \delta \rbrace$ has the additional property that $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}/A_{\alpha}$ is cotorsion-free for all $\alpha < \delta$, the answer is negative.

Has there been any further progress on this question?

One could replace $\omega$ by any countable infinite index set $A$, for example $\mathbb{Q}$, if this might help. Section 6 of George Bergman's paper exploits this possibility to define unusual subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$: http://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/papers/free_dual.pdf

My initial misguided thought had been to seek a forcing adding a "pawn", i.e. a new real $r \in {}^{\omega}{\omega}$ (or similar) such that the old and new Baer-Specker groups would nevertheless be isomorphic in the generic extension; one might then try to build a chain by adding enough pawns. Pawns do not exist, since every epimorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$ is a direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}^{I}$ and a cotorsion group for some $I$, but $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega} \cap V$ is cotorsion-free. Forcings that add epimorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$ onto $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega} \cap V$ appear not to add reals.

Comment: I assume that $\ \mathbb Z^\omega =\mathbb Z^{\aleph_0}\ $ is the additive group of **all** integer sequences (?).

Comment: A paper on group $\ \mathbb Z^{\aleph_0}\ $ was published a time ago by Stanisław Mrówka.

Comment: @Włodzimierz: $\aleph_0$ denotes a cardinal, $\omega$ denotes an ordinal. Sequences are naturally indexed by ordinals.

Comment: Oh, @Asaf, really?!

Comment: @Włodzimierz: I was just pointing out that $\Bbb Z^\omega$ is in fact the appropriate notation. Not $\Bbb Z^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: (1) It so happens, @Asaf, that Andreas Blass and John Irwin in their paper used notation $\ \mathbb Z^{\aleph_0}.\ $ Just in case, I wanted to make sure (without studying the issue too much ahead of time) that there is no other group $\ \mathbb Z^{\omega}\ $ hidden somewhere deep further in the paper.

Comment: (2) While perhaps here $\ \mathbb Z^\omega\ $ is **to me** a preferable notation (specific), nevertheless this group is isomorphic to all such groups $\ \mathbb Z^A\ $ with $\ |A|=\aleph_0.\ $ Furthermore, selecting    some other set $\ A\ $ may have advantages for a particular construction or some other applications. It's similar to square matrices, where index set doesn't have to be $\ \{1\ldots n\}^2\ $ but some $\ S^2\ $ related to the respective applications (in combinatorics or StatisticalmMechanics or other).

Comment: About Stanisław Mrówka's paper: the paper was not about the group of all sequences but about all bounded sequences. (This time I remember better, I believe). I hope that you will find his paper still interesting in the given context.

Comment: Thanks; I have clarified the notation to avoid any doubt. (The subgroup of all bounded sequences is free; $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$ is only $\aleph_{1}$-free, not $\aleph_{2}$-free.)

Comment: This paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0508146v6.pdf might be of relevance.

Comment: @TomekKania: You have made my day. :)

Comment: In a comment to an erased message, I asked whether it is true that every subgroup of $Z^N$ containing $2Z^N$ (I write $Z=\mathbb{Z}$, $N=\mathbb{N}$) is isomorphic to $Z^N$. (This would have implied a positive answer to the question.) This is not true, because, writing $c$ for continuum, the number of subgroups of $Z^N$ containing $2Z^N$ is $2^c$ while the number of subgroups of $Z^N$ isomorphic to $Z^N$ is $c$ (because the cardinal of Hom$(Z^N,Z^N)$ is $c$). Still I'm wondering if there's a reasonable description of which  subgroups of $Z^N$ containing $2Z^N$ are isomorphic to $Z^N$.

Comment: And without the cardinality argument: every endomorphism of the discrete group $Z^N$ is continuous for the natural Polish (product) topology. So their images are far from arbitrary.